# How do I perform model binding on a HTTP POST in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

I want to bind my HTTP POST parameters to Azure functions, and want to ensure the untrusted data is correctly mapped to my model class.

Right now I'm using a mime type of `application/json` , and I may need to also support FORM Post and Protobuf.

- Since I know support for the latter is a bit complex, how can I perform simple model binding for JSON data?

I've spent a lot of time reading about HTTP triggers, skimming all pages of the Azure Function docs, but don't see anything that helps with this issue.  I suspect there is a lower level technology I need to research (webjobs?) for this.

Answer (score 3):

If your HttpTrigger function is configured to accept JSON POST requests, you can bind to your custom model type as follows:

```
using System.Net;

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(Person person, HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    return person.FirstName == null
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Who are you?")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"Hello {person.FirstName}!");
}
```